# How to upgrade PostGIS in OSGEO-Live Xubuntu virtual machine?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, linux, update

I have downlaoded the [OSGEO-Live 6.0](http://live.osgeo.org/en/index.html) virtual machine running Linux Xubuntu.  I have it running through [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) on a Windows machine.  It currently comes preinstalled with a lot of GIS software, including PostGIS 1.5.  I would like to upgrade PostGIS to 2.x.

Having not used linux much, what is the best method to upgrade PostGIS from 1.5 to 2.x on the Xubuntu virtual machine?  Since I just downloaded the Live-DVD, we can assume there is no data that needs to be retained.

Comment: useful link - http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28933/migrating-to-linux-from-windows

Comment: Would advise using ubuntu clean VirtualBox and use this guide for PostGIS - http://linfiniti.com/2012/05/installing-postgis-2-0-on-ubuntu/ have been using this for a good few months without issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the instructions from [Installing PostGIS 2.0 on ubuntu](http://linfiniti.com/2012/05/installing-postgis-2-0-on-ubuntu) on linfiniti.com:

1)

- sudo apt-add-repository ppa:sharpie/for-science  # To get GEOS 3.3.2
- sudo apt-add-repository ppa:sharpie/postgis-nightly
- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.1-postgis

2) create a new database.

3) create postgis extension: CREATE EXTENSION postgis;

4) confirm the version: select postgis_full_version();

should be something like:

> "POSTGIS="2.0.1 r9979" GEOS="3.3.3-CAPI-1.7.4" PROJ="Rel. 4.8.0, 6
>   March 2012" GDAL="GDAL 1.9.2, released 2012/10/08" LIBXML="2.7.8"
>   RASTER"

Comment: So I did a `select version()` and it said the OSGEO Live DVD 6.0 is running postgresql 9.1.5.  Running `select postgis_full_version()` says it is PostGIS 1.5.3.  After creating a new DB, then `CREATE EXTENSION postgis`, I got  `ERROR: could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/9.1/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory.`  Thoughts?

Comment: [This post](http://answerpot.com/showthread.php?3930983-where+is+postgis.sql%3F) to the postgis user list suggests I would need to build PostGIS 2.0 from source...

Comment: Strange... I do the same. Do you have postgis-2.0 folder ? /usr/share/postgresql/9.1/contrib/postgis-2.0

Comment: nope, just ../postgis-1.5.  Did you install postgis-2.0 after you downloaded the VM?

Comment: I guess I did (and forgot!) using this: http://linfiniti.com/2012/05/installing-postgis-2-0-on-ubuntu

Comment: Thank you very much.  Following the instructions on the linfiniti blog got me upgraded!