# How to install PostgreSQL 9.2 with PostGIS 2.0 on Ubuntu 11.10 (or higher)?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, postgis

I have read this question: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25033/install-postgis-v2-for-postgresql-v9-2, but it didn't resolve my problem.

I added the [PostgreSQL backports PPA](http://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/) and installed the `postgresql-9.2` package, but there is no package for PostGIS.

Comment: I think you should ask the PostGIS people whether there will be a package soon or not.

Comment: if you're really that anxious for it, you could install [from source](http://download.osgeo.org/postgis/source/postgis-2.0.1.tar.gz)

Answer (score 1):

**How to Get Started with PostGIS 2.0 on Ubuntu 12.04 (precise)**

(only tested on a Oracle VM) see [Migrating to Linux from Windows](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28933/migrating-to-linux-from-windows) previous install.

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:sharpie/for-science
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:sharpie/postgis-stable
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.2-postgis2
```

Then build

http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostGIS20Ubuntu1204
(replace postgresql-9.1 with postgresql-9.2)

Comment: The last line with `postgresql-9.2-postgis2` doesn't work, unfortunately they only have PostgreSQL 9.1 support for now.

Comment: what does "then build" mean???

Comment: I get this error: W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/sharpie/for-science/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

Answer (score 0):

You may download the source file and build it by yourself:

**Install GEOS(for topology support)**

```
wget http://download.osgeo.org/geos/geos-3.3.9.tar.bz2
tar xfj geos-3.3.9.tar.bz2
cd geos-3.3.9
./configure
make
sudo make install
cd..
```

**Install PostGIS 2.0**

```
wget http://download.osgeo.org/postgis/source/postgis-2.0.6.tar.gz
tar xfz postgis-2.0.6.tar.gz
cd postgis-2.0.6
./configure
make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
sudo make comments-install
```

Source: [how to install postgresql 9.2 + postgis 2.0](http://technobytz.com/install-postgresql-9-2-postgis-2-0-ubuntu.html)