# Install PostGIS on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: postgis, ubuntu

I am trying to install PostGIS on Ubuntu 12.04 and I think everything is installed correctly except for postgresql. I followed this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42598/how-to-install-postgresql-9-2-with-postgis-2-0-on-ubuntu-11-10-or-higher). I get the following error and nothing I do seems to satisfy the unmet dependency.

```
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/postgresql-9.1-postgis_2.0.1-2~precise3_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/lib/rtpostgis-2.0.so', which is also in package postgresql-9.1-postgis2 2.0.0-1ubuntu1~ppa18~precise1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/postgresql-9.1-postgis_2.0.1-2~precise3_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

A little  help for this ubuntu/gis novice.

Comment: Do you really need Postgres 9.2?

Comment: Is your PostgreSQL 9.2 64bits version? Because if PostGIS is 32bits version, maybe they don't "match". Few years ago I faced a weird and similar problem and finally it was that my PostgreSQL was 64 and PostGIS (in that moment it was 1.3.3 or 1.3.5 version) could not work over this version. I just switched Postgre to 32 bits.

Comment: First, thank you for the edit, I couldn't figure out why the error code split like that and I got frustrated trying to correct it.

I am not sure what I need. I have been reading posts about PostGIS and thought I would install so that I can start learning and play with it. Any correction for installation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Sharpie is alright, but recently UbuntuGis team came in with some stable packages: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ppa?field.series_filter=precise, try them.

```
apt-add-repository deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu precise main 
apt-add-repository deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu precise main
apt-get install postgis
```

Also, http://postgis.net/source has a good build manual, till today I used it more often than package installation.

Comment: This method also requires adding the repo key or you'll get a warning and possible a fail that the repo can't be authenticated.    sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 314DF160
OR use the [ppa method](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA/InstallingSoftware)