# Can't get Tiger Geocoder to work in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, tiger

I've installed the PostGIS Tiger Geocoder according to [these instructions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/81907/install-postgis-and-tiger-data-in-ubuntu-12-04) and loaded in data for the state of New York.

Unfortunately, when I try to geocode something...

```
ny_tiger=# SELECT g.rating, ST_X(g.geomout) As lon, ST_Y(g.geomout) As lat, 
(addy).address As stno, (addy).streetname As street, 
(addy).streettypeabbrev As styp, (addy).location As city, (addy).stateabbrev As st, (addy).zip 
FROM geocode('350 Fifth Ave, New York, NY 10118') As g;                                                                
 rating | lon | lat | stno | street | styp | city | st | zip 
--------+-----+-----+------+--------+------+------+----+-----
(0 rows)
```

So that's not great.

I noticed when loading things in I got a ton of errors like this:

```
Unable to open tl_2013_36123_addr.shp or tl_2013_36123_addr.SHP.
tl_2013_36123_addr.dbf: shape (.shp) or index files (.shx) can not be opened, will just import attribute data.
```

Is that the problem? How do I fix that?

Comment: What version of PostGIS?

Comment: It's PostGIS 2.1, Postgres 9.3

Comment: The notices are expected.  When I wrote the loader, I wanted a generic load pattern for all tables at the cost of having some notices. It is more of a notice than an error.  addr tables never have accompanying geometry so when you use shp2pgsql and you don't use the switch to only load attribute, it tries to load spatial, gives a warning if no spatial, and then falls back on loading only attribute data.

Answer (score 4):

I must've done something wrong in following those instructions, as clearing and re-loading the data from scratch yielded a working system.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your Dockerfile, it seems like the the output from `loader_generate_nation_script()` is never run
https://github.com/similitude/tiger-geocoder/blob/master/Dockerfile#L48