# No results for PostGIS TIGER geocoder extension

Tags: postgis, geocoding, census, tiger

Similar to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/95486/cant-get-tiger-geocoder-to-work-in-postgis), my TIGER geocoder extension in PostGIS isn't returning any results. It seemed to all install correctly, so I imported DC, and:

`psql -d geocoder -c "SELECT g.rating, ST_X(geomout) As lon, ST_Y(geomout) As lat, (addy).* FROM geocode('1731 New Hampshire Avenue Northwest, Washington, DC 20010', 1) As g;"`

... from the command line returns:

`rating | lon | lat | address | predirabbrev | streetname | streettypeabbrev | postdirabbrev | internal | location | stateabbrev | zip | parsed 
--------+-----+-----+---------+--------------+------------+------------------+---------------+----------+----------+-------------+-----+--------
(0 rows)`

Unlike that other question, I have a repeatable case, since I'm trying to set this up in a [Dockerfile](https://github.com/simupedia/tiger-geocoder/blob/master/Dockerfile). Can anyone see what might be wrong here? Is there a step that I've messed up?

Ubuntu (Trusty), PostgreSQL 9.3, PostGIS 2.1 (installed 'manually', i.e. not as an extension), attempting to use TIGER 2013 data.

Answer (score 2):

Check if the data loaded successfully (sometimes a lot of census FTP dowloads fail and the load will continue. You won't know unless you captured that error log and check it). I just ran this query and geocodes perfectly using TIGER 2013.

```
SELECT g.rating, ST_X(g.geomout) As lon, ST_Y(g.geomout) As lat, 
(addy).address As stno, (addy).streetname As street, 
(addy).streettypeabbrev As styp, (addy).location As city, (addy).stateabbrev As st,(addy).zip 
FROM geocode(normalize_address('1731 New Hampshire Avenue Northwest, Washington, DC 20010'), 1) As g;  

 rating |        lon        |       lat        | stno |    street     | styp |    city    | st |  zip  
--------+-------------------+------------------+------+---------------+------+------------+----+-------
      1 | -77.0398083968318 | 38.9133648716727 | 1731 | New Hampshire | Ave  | Washington | DC | 20009
```

Comment: has something changed in recent versions? When I run the query shown in this answer I get no results.

Comment: it seems in my installation the zcta5 table is empty and there is no row for it in loader_lookuptables. I guess that is why I get no results.