# Installing PostGIS tiger geocoder?

Tags: geocoding, postgis-2.0, tiger

I am getting the TIGER geocoding feature set up on my windows 7 64 bit box (PostGIS 2.1; Postgres 9.4).

I followed the steps outlined here to generate the batch scripts and ran them last night:
http://postgis.net/docs/postgis_installation.html#install_tiger_geocoder_extension

Upon inspecting the batch log, there are a bunch of what appears to be soft fails on importing the data.

```
NOTICE:  INSERT INTO tiger_data.ca_addr(tlid,fromhn,tohn,side,zip,plus4,fromtyp,totyp,arid,mtfcc) SELECT tlid,fromhn,tohn,side,zip,plus4,fromtyp,totyp
,arid,mtfcc FROM tiger_staging.ca_addr;
CONTEXT:  SQL function "loader_load_staged_data" statement 1
Unable to open C:\gisdata\temp\tl_2015_06105_addr.shp or C:\gisdata\temp\tl_2015_06105_addr.SHP.
C:\gisdata\temp\tl_2015_06105_addr.dbf: shape (.shp) or index files (.shx) can not be opened, will just import attribute data.

NOTICE:  INSERT INTO tiger_data.ca_addr(tlid,fromhn,tohn,side,zip,plus4,fromtyp,totyp,arid,mtfcc) SELECT tlid,fromhn,tohn,side,zip,plus4,fromtyp,totyp
,arid,mtfcc FROM tiger_staging.ca_addr;
CONTEXT:  SQL function "loader_load_staged_data" statement 1
Unable to open C:\gisdata\temp\tl_2015_06107_addr.shp or C:\gisdata\temp\tl_2015_06107_addr.SHP.
C:\gisdata\temp\tl_2015_06107_addr.dbf: shape (.shp) or index files (.shx) can not be opened, will just import attribute data.
```

Checking `wget` and `unzip`, however, they seem to both be fetched and unzipped properly:

```
C:\gisdata\ftp2.census.gov\geo\tiger\TIGER2015\ADDR>"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" e C:\gisdata\ftp2.census.gov\geo\tiger\TIGER2015\ADDR\tl_2015_06107_addr.zip  -o\gisdata\temp\  

7-Zip [64] 15.14 : Copyright (c) 1999-2015 Igor Pavlov : 2015-12-31

Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 745422 bytes (728 KiB)

Extracting archive: C:\gisdata\ftp2.census.gov\geo\tiger\TIGER2015\ADDR\tl_2015_06107_addr.zip
--
Path = C:\gisdata\ftp2.census.gov\geo\tiger\TIGER2015\ADDR\tl_2015_06107_addr.zip
Type = zip
Physical Size = 745422

Everything is Ok

Files: 5
Size:       3706093
Compressed: 745422
```

What is more, there are actually plenty of rows in the `tiger_data.ca_addr` table: 2,940,520 (although surely way below the number of rows there should be for California.

I am not sure where to start looking for clues here, so pointers very welcome!

---

I found another mention of this [issue](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/95486/cant-get-tiger-geocoder-to-work-in-postgis?rq=1)--there is no `tl_2015_06107_addr.shp` (and similar) shp-files; only the `dbf`s are shipped from the census bureau, so the warning is generic. So the data seemingly loaded, I am just not getting results.

---

On Windows, I can geocode, but time is prohibitive: This request takes 136 seconds for one(!) address.

```
SELECT g.rating, ST_X(g.geomout) As lon, ST_Y(g.geomout) As lat, 
    (addy).address As stno, (addy).streetname As street, 
    (addy).streettypeabbrev As styp, (addy).location As city, (addy).stateabbrev As st,(addy).zip 
    FROM geocode('1355 Market St #900, San Francisco, CA 94103') As g;
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the warnings, I received the same warnings.

Regarding the geocode time of 136 seconds, I have 37 states loaded and your request takes 2.8 seconds on my windows 64 bit box.  If you have more states loaded, it will take longer.  If you have fewer states loaded than I, then you may need to double check your indexes and modify your PostgreSQL server config.  See [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/192593/postgis-how-can-i-improve-the-response-time-for-getting-the-routed-distance-bet) for links.