# How to install PostgreSQL and PostGIS on Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, ubuntu

I have upgraded my OS from Ubuntu 12.10 to 13.10. I had a clean installation of 13.10 version.   Can someone please suggest which version of PostgreSQL and PostGIS can be installed on Ubuntu 13.10 version and how to install it?

I have looked at the steps given in [How to install PostgreSQL 9.2 with PostGIS 2.0 on Ubuntu 11.10 (or higher)?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42598/how-to-install-postgresql-9-2-with-postgis-2-0-on-ubuntu-11-10-or-higher)? But the three repos are not adding after update.

Hence that answer is not helping me.

Comment: Please test those code in Ubuntu 13.10 and mark it duplicate again

Comment: Have you tried the duplicate question's suggested steps?

Comment: Yes. The three repo is not adding after update. that is why the installation couldn't be completed

Comment: You can install Postgresql 9.3, PostGIS 2.1, and the latest PGAdmin on Ubuntu 13 from these instructions: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bxh7puyDgHHoRG9MajJNNVVHSHM/edit?usp=sharing