# Start postgresql+postgis without installation on Windows

Tags: postgis, postgresql, postgis-2.0, windows, bat

I have used Windows7x64 and want start PostgreSQL+POSTGIS without installation process. I copy PostgresSQl\9.1 folder from other laptop to c:\opt. I need create .bat file with enviroment variables and add pg_ctl.exe with any parameters. is it possible start Postgresql server without creating Windows services and using any regedit manipulations?
Sorry if my question is not correct compiled

Comment: The question why do you need to do this? Looking at the postgis install there 12 or so regedit entries required.

Comment: Only other method is via a Virtual Box running Linux (i.e.Ubuntu and bridging the virtual network adapters to appear on the same machine).

Comment: See the old post http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28933/migrating-to-linux-from-windows/28951#28951

Comment: Thanx for your help but now I need the Jakub Kania's method. It needs for a scrypting process in my issue...

Comment: i created by installer(.exe) and copy folder to another computer i start manual with command line following "../bin"pg_ctl -D ../data

Comment: Could you expand a bit on your answer?

Answer (score 5):

[PostGIS Windows dl site](http://postgis.net/windows_downloads) provides information about running it without installing. [The blog it links to](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/172-Starting-PostgreSQL-in-windows-without-install.html) has all the info needed.

Comment: Jakub Kania, Thanx a lot. I've used something like that))

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it is possible to run postgres without setting up the service and the `postgres` user.

The client has to know what port the database is listening to etc.

What you can do is setting up the database identically on two computers, and exchange the data directories if needed.

Comment: I've just installed it om the one of the laptop then copy all directory to another laptop, finally start pgsql with cmd-file. See bellow... Thanx for a reply